# How to deploy a kubernetes yaml for an optional pvc?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a kubernetes yaml for a pod that declares a pvc volume that I want to mount. However, if the PVC doesn't exist, the pod will stay in the Pending state indefinitely.
Since the yaml will be used in multiple environments, where some will use the pvc and others don't, is there a way to kubernetes to just ignore the non-existant pvc?
Thank you

I searched for optional arguments on documentation but didn't found any

Comment: Why do you release a YAML file that mounts a Volume in environments where you don't have the Volume? If it's a Manifests "handling" problem, I suggest you use kustomize; I'll give you some links in case.

Comment: Alternative is to user helm with helmcharts (and helmfile for further possibilities). This is what i prefer.

Comment: @glv I'll use the PVC to store logs for Staging environment. However, the PR will be merged later into Production and I wasn't allowed to create the volume there at the moment.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't manage Manifests with kustomize/helm, you could deploy your YAML file commenting out the volume part. However this is an anti-pattern, because you would have to promote files as-is from a lower environment to a higher one.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your mention - "Since the yaml will be used in multiple environments, where some will use the pvc and others don't...":

If you mean a "make the pvc available on-demand only as and when the (application in the)container needs it" : You might want to review to [dynamic provisioning of PVCs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/), via Storage Classes.

For static PVCs:
When pvc is declared in kubernetes yaml file, it's a declaration indicating it will be used **for** the deployment to keep it available for the container.

Assuming the pvc and associated pv definitions you have in your yaml are valid pointing to working and available storage as and when needed by the container needing the storage, it's upto the (application in the)container whether to use the pvc or not for storing the logs or whatever that might be. So it's optional as per the needs of the container image, and not as per the kubernetes platform because kubernetes wouldn't know whether or not the application needs it, ahead of time.